# Real Analysis Riemann integrals with piece wise function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

This is part of my homework assignment and I have been stuck on it for a few days.

Let *f* be the function on **[0,1]** given by *f(x)*= { 1 if x does not = 1/2 and 2 if x=1/2

Prove *f* is Riemann integrable and compute ∫f(x)dx from 0 to 1

[Hint from text: For each ε > 0, find a partition *P* so that Up(f) - Lp(f) ≤ 3]

My professor also made a suggestion to do a Riemann sum from the midpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint let us partition $[0,1 ] $ into $2^{n+1}$ intervals of length $2^n$, by splitting the interval at the midpoint, then continuing in that fashion.

So our partition is $P_n=\{[x_i,x_{i+1}]=[\frac{(i-1)}{2^{n}},\frac{i}{2^n}],i=1,...,2^n\}$
Now our lower sum is $L(P,f)=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{2^n}\inf_{x\in[x_k,x_k+1]}f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{2^n}=1$, and our upper sum is:

$U(P,f)\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{2^n}\sup_{x\in[x_k,x_k+1]}f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-2}\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{4}{2^n}=1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$

Now: $U(P,f)-L(P,f)=
1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}-1=\frac {1}{2^{n-2}}-\frac {1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac {1}{2^{n-1}}\le \epsilon $, for $n$ sufficiently large.
Hope that helps.